# Can I get access to users microphone in mobile browsers?

Tags: html, mobile, safari, webkit, microphone

The Google Voice WebApp somehow uses the microphone as input as I have read here: 
http://gizmodo.com/5456815/google-voice-finally-heads-to-iphone-palm-pre-with-html5-webapp

How can I achieve this besides using Google Chrome? It seems to be possible in Mobile Safari.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'd love to know how to record audio in mobile browsers for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" x-webkit-speech />` is what you are looking for. But it only works in a minimum range of browsers. Hope you can find more with this information.